# Powershell: what script is running and who/what started it

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2019

I have a background powershell script that is eating a lot of CPU. Rather than just killing it, I'd like to know what the script is and hopefully why it was started. This is on a Windows server 2019 lab/evaluation machine. On task manager, my user account is listed as the user running powershell.exe.

e.g. in linux, top will list the command line arguments on bash/python/perl/etcetera so you can tell what commands a generic program is running.

Comment: Use ProcessExplorer https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: `gwmi -class win32_process | select ProcessName, CommandLine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. GPO: Computer \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ Windows Powershell

   - Enable Powershell Script Block Logging
   - Enable Transcripts (eg. C:\PSLog ... create this dir)
2. Event Viewer: Applications and Services Logs \ Microsoft \ Windows \ Powershell \ Operational
3. Read Event Viewer and Transcripts

And yes, do what "Zoredache" suggested.